# Prisma with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, prisma

I have two databases one is a postgresql going to be created using prisma running the commands

```
npx prisma db pull
npx prisma generate
```

The second database is a SQL-SERVER that already exists and has data in it, How can I use prisma to query it?

Is there any configuration that I need to do on prisma on in my application?

I'm using NodeJS for this API.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use both databases in the same application?

Comment: Hi my friend!

Yes I need to use both data-bases.

Comment: You would need to create two Prisma Clients, one for each database. I would recommend you to have a look at this GitHub Issue to get idea on how you can implement it: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118